# Python3 socket - What is purpose of chunking network packets

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am new to `socket` module at Python 3. While researching this module I've seen many examples of code where `socket.recv(n)` function was called multiple times to "chunk" data. And almost all of these code examples used patterns like this:

```
with socket.socket() as sock:
    sock.connect((host, port))
    to_read = int(sock.recv(8))
    sock.sendall(b'GOT SIZE')

    chunks = []
    while to_read:
        chunk = sock.recv(chunk_length)
        chunks.append(chunk)
        to_read -= chunk_length
    data = b''.join(chunks)
```

So I have a question: What is purpose of chunking data if you can just use `sock.recv(to_read)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is purpose of chunking data **if you can just use sock.recv(to_read)**

`recv` does not return `to_read` bytes. It return **up to** `to_read` bytes. Especially with large values of `to_read` it is very likely that you need multiple `recv` to get all the requested bytes. Thus, "chunking" is needed to actually receive all the data.

Note that if the goal is to put all received data into a single buffer it would actually be more efficient to not read small chunks but to try to read all data at once and retry for the remaining data again and again until all data are received. This way the least number of `recv` calls and the least number of memory (re)allocations are used.

Comment: What is max length of data to use one chunk and one call of `sock.recv(data_len)`? Is ~8MB too much?

Comment: @Vlad: there is no universal max chunk length. It depends at least on the size of the socket buffer which itself depends on configuration, socket specific setting and maybe more. Apart from that TCP window size is relevant - which is dynamic.